# Is it necessary to use a variable or exactly the property in IDisposable?

Tags: c#, variables, properties, interface, idisposable

When I'm implemeting IDisposable interface, I've work with the `bool disposed` variable, which is in `protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)`.

But I wonder, what if I use not a simple variable, but the property in C# with this situation?

```
class A : IDisposable
{
    bool disposed { get; set; }
...

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                //dispose managed ressources
            }
        }

        disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
```

Comment: Changing between a private field and a private property won't change a lot... why would it? especially for a trivial property (such as an automatically implemented property)...

Comment: There is no need to call GC.SuppressFinalize(this) if there is no finalizer. See this post: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/08/how-to-implement-idisposable-and.html for more info on IDisposable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear whether you are talking about a `disposed` flag or the `disposing` parameter.  If the former, my preferred pattern is to use a `private int` variable, and have the `IDisposable.Dispose` implementation `Interlocked.Exchange` the flag to 1, and call `Dispose(bool)` if it was previously zero; a read-only `protected` or `public` property `Disposed` should indicate whether the flag is set.

As for the `disposing` parameter, the `Dispose(bool)` method should generally only be called with a value of `true`; the effective purpose of the flag is to change the signature from `Dispose()`, thus allowing the use of the same name.  Inheritable classes should generally only have finalizers if their whole purpose centers around finalization (as with e.g. `SafeHandle`) so there's no reason to worry about handling `Dispose(false)`.

Note that if one doesn't block double invocations *before* calling the virtual method, every derived class that wants to be protected will have to define its own redundant flag for that purpose--somewhat wasteful.

Answer (score 2):

This property:

```
bool disposed { get; set; }
```

is almost equivalent to a field. It's effectively this:

```
bool _disposed;
bool disposed { get { return _disposed; } set { _disposed = value; } }
```

Given that both the field and the property are private, and you're not adding any behaviour to the property, I'd just stick with a simple field.

Also note that if you can seal your class (so you don't need to worry about subclasses wanting to override `Disposing(bool)` you can get rid of the `Dispose(bool)` method entirely, and just implement `Dispose()` in a simple way.

Indeed, unless you *need* to keep a flag indicating whether or not the instance has been disposed, you could remove that, too.